# retry a statement inside an array loop in php but with the next value of the array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm here again, learning more and more about PHP, but still have some problems for my scenario, most of my scenario has been programmed and solved without problem, but I found an issue, but to understand it, I need to explain it first:

I have a PHP script which can be invoked by any client and its work is to receive a request, ping to a proxy from a list which I define manually, to know if a proxy is available, if it is available, I proceed to retrieve a response using "curl" with a POST method. The logic is like this:

```
$proxyList = array('192.168.3.41:8013'=> 0, '192.168.3.41:8023'=>0, '192.168.3.41:8033'=>0);
$errorCounter = 0;

foreach ($proxyList as $key => $value){
 if(!isUrlAvailable($key){ //It means it is NOT available so I count errors
    $errorCounter++;
 } else { //It means it is AVAILABLE
    $result = callThisProxy($key);
 }
}
```

The function `"isUrlAvailable"` uses a $fsockopen to know if the proxy is available. If not, I make a `POST` with `CURL` as mentioned before, the function has `callThisProxy()` something like:

```
 $ch = curl_init($proxyUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'xmlQuery='.$rawXml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $info = curl_exec ($ch);
    if($isDebug){echo 'Info in the moment: '.$info.'<br/>';}
    curl_close ($ch);
```

But, we're testing some scenarios, what happen if I turn off the proxy between the verification of the proxy availability and the call? I mean:

```
foreach ($proxyList as $key => $value){
 if(!isUrlAvailable($key){ //It means it is NOT available so I count errors
    $errorCounter++;
 } else { //It means it is AVAILABLE
    $result = callThisProxy($key);//What happen if I kill the proxy when the result is being processed?
 }
}
```

I tested it and when I do that, the $result comes as empty string `''`. But the problem is that I lost that request, and my goal is to retry it with the next `$key` which is a proxy. So, I've been thinking of a `"do, while"` when I invoke the result. But not sure, if it is ok or there's a better way to do it, so please I ask for help with this issue. Thanks in advance for your time any answer is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Im confused, you don't exit out of the loop after calling the proxy, so isn't it going to try the next proxy no matter what the return value of `callThisProxy($key)` is?

Comment: it would try the next proxy, but the result for the proxy that was shutted down will be null or empty, while the objective is to always get a result for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
$result = "";

while ($result == "")
{
    foreach ($proxyList as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!isUrlAvailable($key))
        {
            $errorCounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            $result = callThisProxy($key);
        }
    }
}

// Now check $result, which should contain the first successful callThisProxy()
//   result, or nothing if none of the keys worked.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just keep a list of proxies that you still need to try. When you hit the error or get a valid response then you remove the proxy from the list of proxies to try. If you do not get a good response then keep it in the list and try it again later.

```
$proxiesToTry = $proxyList;
$i = 0;

while (count($proxiesToTry) != 0) {
    // reset to beginning of array
    if($i >= count($proxiesToTry)) 
        $i = 0;

    $proxy = $proxiesToTry[$i];

    if (!isUrlAvailable($proxy)) { //It means it is NOT available so I count errors
        $errorCounter++;
        unset($proxiesToTry[$i]);
    } else { //It means it is AVAILABLE
        $result = callThisProxy($proxy); 
        if($result != "") // If we got a response remove it from the array of proxies to try.
            unset($proxiesToTry[$i]);
    }

    $i++;
}
```

NOTE: You will never break out of this loop if you don't ever get a valid response from some proxy.